# 2d sphere index in spring data mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am working on geospatial query of mongodb,i have executed following query on mongo console

```
db.items.find(
   {
     location:
       { $near :
          {
            $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [77.026638, 28.459497 ] },
            $maxDistance: 10000
          }
       }
   }
)
```

but how can i write this query using spring data mongodb criteria ?

I was trying with using following criteria,but it is not working

```
 Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("location").near(new Point(77.026638, 28.459497)).maxDistance(1000);

        Query query = new Query(criteria);
System.out.println(mongoTemplate.find(query, Item.class));
```

Stack trace

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=geolocation.items limit=0 skip=0
Tree: GEONEAR  field=location maxdist=1.79769e+308 isNearSphere=0
Sort: {}
Proj: {}
 planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException: Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=geolocation.items limit=0 skip=0
Tree: GEONEAR  field=location maxdist=1.79769e+308 isNearSphere=0
Sort: {}
Proj: {}
 planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:1940)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1823)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1616)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:535)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:526)
    at com.samepinch.dao.item.ItemDao$$EPWN0nhQ.getItemsByLocation(ItemDao.java:200)
    at com.samepinch.dao.item.ItemDao$$DPWN0nhQ.getItemsByLocation(Unknown Source)
    at com.samepinch.dao.item.ItemDao.getItemsByLocation(ItemDao.java)
    at com.samepinch.services.item.ItemService.getItemsByLocation(ItemService.java:410)
    at com.samepinch.controllers.item.ItemController.getItemsbyLocation(ItemController.java:222)
    at com.samepinch.controllers.item.ItemController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$33bec54c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.samepinch.controllers.item.ItemController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7fa26c49.getItemsbyLocation(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.OriginalClassInvoker.invoke(OriginalClassInvoker.java:47)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1299)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at com.samepinch.mongodb.springsecurity.filters.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException: Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=geolocation.items limit=0 skip=0
Tree: GEONEAR  field=location maxdist=1.79769e+308 isNearSphere=0
Sort: {}
Proj: {}
 planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query
    at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.throwOnQueryFailure(QueryResultIterator.java:214)
    at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.init(QueryResultIterator.java:198)
    at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.initFromQueryResponse(QueryResultIterator.java:176)
    at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.<init>(QueryResultIterator.java:64)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:86)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:66)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:458)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:546)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:571)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1809)
    ... 105 more
```

My schema is

```
@Document(collection = "items")
public class Item extends BaseEntity{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String itemName;
    private MetadataEnum categoryName;
    private List<SubtypeEnum> attributes;
    private String registerBy;
    boolean isAccessed;
    private String imageUrl;
    private CatagoryPreference catagoryPreference;
    private Date startDate,endDate; 

    private Location location;
}
```

embedded document is :)

```
public class Location {

    private List<Double> coordinates;
    private String type;
    public List<Double> getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }
    public void setCoordinates(List<Double> coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
    public void setRadius(Double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    private Double radius;

}
```

Even i find system index for make sure

```
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "geolocation.notification" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "geolocation.preference" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "geolocation.userItemHistory" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "geolocation.media" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "geolocation.userBasedRecommendation" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "geolocation.users" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "geolocation.authenticationToken" }
{ "v" : 1, "unique" : true, "key" : { "username" : 1 }, "name" : "username", "ns" : "geolocation.users" }
{ "v" : 1, "unique" : true, "key" : { "email" : 1 }, "name" : "email", "ns" : "geolocation.users" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "geolocation.userToUserHistory" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "geolocation.metadata" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "geolocation.mongo_data_model_map" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "element_id" : 1 }, "name" : "element_id_1", "ns" : "geolocation.mongo_data_model_map" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "long_value" : 1 }, "name" : "long_value_1", "ns" : "geolocation.mongo_data_model_map" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "geolocation.preferenceOrder" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "geolocation.counter" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "geolocation.item" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "location" : "2dsphere" }, "name" : "location_2dsphere", "ns" : "geolocation.item", "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2 }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "geolocation.items" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "location" : "2dsphere" }, "name" : "location_2dsphere", "ns" : "geolocation.items", "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2 }
Type "it" for more
> it
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "a" : 1 }, "name" : "a_1", "ns" : "geolocation.items" }
```

My database record look like

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(46602),
    "_class" : "com.samepinch.domain.item.Item",
    "itemName" : "Chandigarh",
    "categoryName" : "TRAVELLING",
    "attributes" : [
        "MOUNTAIN"
    ],
    "isAccessed" : false,
    "imageUrl" : "0bbd8cdb-be5c-4efc-b974-c04fb1903537itemcompressed.jpg",
    "catagoryPreference" : "BOTH",
    "startDate" : ISODate("2015-12-09T18:30:00Z"),
    "endDate" : ISODate("2015-12-09T18:30:00Z"),
    "location" : {
        "coordinates" : [
            76.76641440000003,
            30.72642125251779
        ],
        "type" : "Point",
        "radius" : 8504.948210235696
    },
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2015-12-09T10:27:42.519Z"),
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2015-12-09T10:27:42.519Z")
}
```

I have created 2d spheare index on collection,but i don't know on why it is giving me this error.

Comment: have you tried using `GeoJsonPoint` instead of `Point` to indicate usage of GeoJSON format? Which versions of spring-data-mongodb, mongo-java-driver and mongodb server are you using?

Comment: I am using spring data mongodb v 1.7.1 and mongo java driver 2.13.0

Comment: thanks, my bad - totally overlooked that you need to use `nearSphere` ->  `Criteria.where("location").nearSphere(new GeoJsonPoint(77.026638, 28.459497)).ma...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change data storage instead of:

```
"location" : {
    "coordinates" : [
        76.76641440000003,
        30.72642125251779
    ],
    "type" : "Point",
    "radius" : 8504.948210235696
}
```

to

```
"location" : {
    "coordinates" : [
        76.76641440000003,
        30.72642125251779
    ],
    "type" : "Point"
}
```

I think for "Point" type you have wrong data type. It should only have longitude, latitude for geographic coordinates. You should not include "raduis".

Check valid [GeoJsons](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#appendix-a-geometry-examples).

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced this issue. After so much struggle i found it without using Criteria. This below is using not using spring...i.e. only java
This is definitely gonna help u out

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost" , 27017 );
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("services");
    DBCollection collection=  db.getCollection("timezone");
    BasicDBObject point = new BasicDBObject("type", "Point");
    double[] ptCordinate={lat,longi};
    point.put("coordinates", ptCordinate);

    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(
        "geometry", new BasicDBObject(
            "$near", new BasicDBObject(
                "$geometry", point
            )
        )
    );
    collection.findOne(query);
```